# Universal link not working on testflight iOS (Expo)

Tags: ios, react-native, hyperlink, expo, ios-universal-links

I've been trying to add the universal links to my app. currently the scheme links work fine. I am working with expo, and expo linking I have this type of links working:

```
dandy://SquadSingle?id=6111b70f76cefd027b664270
```

And I want it to work as:

```
www.mysite.com/SquadSingle?id=6111b70f76cefd027b664270
```

The ASSA file in my website is this one, located in mysite.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association:

```
{
 "applinks": {
  "apps" : [],
  "details": [
   {
    "appIDs": ["<TeamID>.<BundleID>"],
    "components":[
        {
        "/": "/SquadSingle/",
            "comment": "Mathces any URL whose path starts with /SquadSingle/"
        },
      ]
   },
   {
     "appID": "<TeamID>.<BundleID>",
     "paths": [
        "/SquadSingle/*",
        "*"
     ]
   }
  ]
 }
 "activitycontinuation": {
   "apps": [
       "<TeamID>.<BundleID>"
   ]
 }
}
```

I added the configuration of associatedDomains to the app.json like this:

```
"ios": {
  ...
  "associatedDomains": [
    "applinks: <mysite>.com"
  ],
  ...
}
```

I have already enabled the associated domains in my developer.apple

I uploaded my .IPA to App Store connect to try on testflight but but even then the app does not open the desired links.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Have you [validated(https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) your ASSA file? Have you enabled [developer mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) on your associate domain to bypass Apple's CDN?

Comment: Yep! I already did it. But it does not work yet!

Comment: Which thing?  Both things?  You can [Use sysdiagnose](https://www.wwt.com/article/using-sysdiagnose-on-ios-to-troubleshoot-universal-links)  on your device to check the state of your apple site association file.  Also your `components` entry doesn't match the comment.  If you want to support url paths that *start with* SquadSingle then you need `/SquadSingle/*`

Comment: @saulcontreras Did you get this working ? if yes, could you help me, i'm also stuck with this now.